# file_get_contents( [file direct link] ) not working in php anymore

Tags: box-api

I have an enterprise box account, and I was tasked with creating a crawler that would scan an account on box and save all meta information (including a direct link) in a local database. This works fine.

in PHP I have also built a function that downloads the documents (via the direct link I obtained from the api) and extracts readable text from them. This was working perfect a week ago, yesterday however this stopped working completely. I'm using the file_get_contents() function to download the file, and currently it only retrieves the document's file size rather than the document itself, which I find strange. I have tried CURL and I get the same result, it seems box is responding to my direct file requests with the file size instead of the actual file.

The files are ALL open access, so anyone with a direct link can download the file without logging in. I have also tried running this code on another server in another hosting company and I get the exact same result. I have tested my code by accessing other files from other locations (not box) and it works fine.

It's important to note that this was working fine just a week ago, but now it doesn't work at all. Nothing changed in between on my end, (that I know of). Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hi Daniel, something must've changed in the last week if it's just suddenly stopped working, configuration changes, PHP upgrade, code changes?

Comment: Hi Cristian, thanks for your response.

In my debugging I noticed my code works for any file in any other location. I get no error messages of any kind. If there was a problem with my code it wouldn't work at all for any files regardless of the location, but this problem occurs only when accessing files from Box. Also I tried running this code on another server from another host and it still didn't work. Again, this code was not changed, it was working a week ago just fine and it worked fine for months.

Comment: You've also checked the Apache error logs for any info? Unless it's something trivial such as using an incorrect file location, I'd suggest the issue is permission related. What user is Apache (I assume) running under?

Comment: Unfortunately I currently do not have root access for viewing the error logs. The file location can't be wrong because I have tried hard coding a direct file link to a document and it still did not work. When pasting this exact link into my browser I am able to download the document. 

The response headers I receive from Box when executing file_get_contents() tell me that Box is responding with content type of text/html. The only thing file_get_contents() outputs is the document's file size, which is accurate.

Comment: Considering that it is a specific directory which file_get_contents fails for, I'd suggest investigating permission issues. Ensure that the ownership of the files within this directory match the user which is running the Apache process.

Comment: file_get_contents() works if I download a document from my personal server. If the permissions were not adequate it would not work for any document regardless of the location it's coming from. I have also ensured in Box that I have the adequate permissions for accessing the files directly, and I do. All files in the box account are "open access".

Comment: What URL are you hitting to get your API response?  Are you going to <yourco>.box.com/api/2.0 or www.box.com?